# flex lexer overwriting first two bytes of stdin buffer

Tags: c, flex-lexer

The following [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) source file generates a scanner that appears to overwrite the first two bytes of the `stdin` buffer with null bytes once it's done tokenizing it. Is that expected behavior?

```
%{
const char *firstChar;
%}

%%

.* firstChar = yytext;
<<EOF>> return 0;

%%

int main(void){
    yylex();
    printf("%d %d\n", firstChar[0], firstChar[1]);
    yylex_destroy();
    return 0;
}
```

It captures the initial value of `yytext` in `firstChar`, and prints out the numeric values of its first two bytes after a call to `yylex`. Compiling and running the scanner:

```
$ flex example.l
$ gcc -o example lex.yy.c
$ echo -n "foobar" | ./example
0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yytext` does not point into the '`stdin` buffer'. It points into a private buffer inside 'flex'. There is no guarantee anywhere about what 'flex' does or doesn't to to its own buffer. That's its business. You're supposed to copy data from it if you want to save it.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess assuming that memory *will* be modified unless specified otherwise is a good rule of thumb (duh). I also found some [official documentation](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/A-Note-About-yytext-And-Memory.html) to back that up.

Answer (score 1):

lex/flex always do some lookahead.  Bear in mind that `yytext` is simply the name given to the matched string -- which includes the end-of-file rule.

If you want to capture the *first* occurrence of `yytext` in a given rule, and have it persist, you should make that part of the rule, e.g.,

```
.* if (firstChar == 0) firstChar = strdup(yytext);
```

Comment: That rule only gets executed once (I initially had a similar conditional but stripped it out to simplify the example), so `firstChar` will contain the first and last value of `yytext`. Anyway, I'm still unclear why flex is overwriting the first two bytes. If I throw a `printf("%.*s\n", yyleng, yytext);` into the `.*` rule, it prints `foobar`, but after `yylex()` returns the `fo` will have been 0'd out, so I only see `obar` (and at that point I actually have to use `fwrite()` to print it, since `printf()` appears to terminate on encountering a null byte).

Comment: Take a look at the generated ".c" file to see the places where `yytext` is mentioned (and the associated `yytext_ptr`).  There are a lot of places where it is updated.  (flex has no low-level debug switch, else I might advise you to turn that on and see -- but the "-d" switch can show a fair amount of detail).